# How to created stacked bar plot with spesific value?

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation, kaggle

I was trying to explore this dataset
https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/thedevastator/analyzing-credit-card-spending-habits-in-india/code?datasetId=2731425&sortBy=voteCount
and I want to create a stacked bar of the 4 countries with the highest spend
I use this syntax

```
dfg = df.groupby(['City']).sum().sort_values(by='Amount', ascending = False).head(4).reset_index()
fig = px.histogram(dfg, x='City', y = 'Amount')
fig.show()
```

but I found it difficult to make it stacked, I tried using pivot but it ain't work too, any way to make this possible?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a grouped bar plot, you should use the [`px.bar`](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.bar.html) command, not `px.histogram`. To have stacked bars you need to add a new column with a dummy group (or meaningful if you have several countries):

```
px.bar(dfg.assign(country='India'), x='country', color='City', y = 'Amount')
```

Output:

[image]

To get the country from the original City column:

```
df[['City', 'Country']] = df['City'].str.split(', ', n=1, expand=True)

dfg = (df.groupby(['City', 'Country']).sum().sort_values(by='Amount', ascending = False)
         .groupby('Country').head(4).reset_index()
       )

px.bar(dfg, x='Country', color='City', y = 'Amount')
```